Adding User Data To Socket In NestJS Guard
I have a guard for mijn Gateway and want to add a user's data to a socket so that i can access the data in the gateway's handlers but am having no success. This is what i have:
@Injectable()
export class MySocketAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
// Fetching user data and other stuff are removed for clarity.

let socket = context.switchToWs().getClient<Socket>();
// "user" is an attribute am adding to socket
socket.user = new User(userId);
return true.
}

}

In mijn Gateway handlers - handleConnection(...) and handleMessage(...) - i don't get any user property on the Socket. The user property doesn't even exist on the socket in both functions.
    export class ChannelGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    
        @UseGuards(MySocketAuthGuard)
            handleConnection(@ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
        console.log(socket.user);
        }

       @UseGuards(MySocketAuthGuard)
       @SubscribeMessage('message')
       async handleMessage(@ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket) {
        console.log(socket.user);
       }

    }

In the functions above the user property doesn't even exist on the socket. I was hoping that it will even exist in the handleMessage(...) function.
What am i doing wrong?
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Nest doesn't support guards at handleConnection level. but you can do like that
// in gateway
async handleConnection(socket) {
    const user: User = await this.jwtService.verify(
      socket.handshake.query.token,
      true
    );

    this.connectedUsers = [...this.connectedUsers, String(user._id)];

    // Send list of connected users
    this.server.emit('users', this.connectedUsers);
  }

// in jwtService
  async verify(token: string, isWs: boolean = false): Promise<User | null> {
    try {
      const payload = <any>jwt.verify(token, APP_CONFIG.jwtSecret);
      const user = await this.usersService.findById(payload.sub._id);

      if (!user) {
        if (isWs) {
          throw new WsException('Unauthorized access');
        } else {
          throw new HttpException(
            'Unauthorized access',
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
          );
        }
      }

      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      if (isWs) {
        throw new WsException(err.message);
      } else {
        throw new HttpException(err.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      }
    }
  }

If this doesn't work for you or you dont like this solution, you can check out THIS LINK and OTHER LINK
There are detailed discussions on this topic at these links. I hope it will be useful.

Thanks for your reply. Your solution is ok if you want the user in the handleConnection(...) function. I also want the user in the event handling functions (I have updated my post with an event handling function).
